# View data requested by WordPress plugin in browser?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, plugins

I've installed a WordPress plugin that is fetching data via a remote server which it converts into a visual output and would like to see the original format.

The plugin runs while on screen and the data is being parsed with Javascript, so is there any way to intercept this in a browser with an event listener or something similar?

The data it's fetching is possibly Jason if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just for debugging and developing? Then use the built-in browser developer tools, which generally have a 'Network' tab to see the data being retrieved.

- [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)
- ...etc

Comment: Perfect I was being dumb and forgot that you have to set the Network to record, it's not a feature I've used much.